# Cyclic queue using an array

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, queue, circular-list

I tried to implement a cyclic Queue using an array, as a task from a coding interview.

Please comment about style, as well as any edge cases I may have missed.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace CirucularArray
{
    [TestClass]
    public class CyclicQueueUsingArray
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void QueueTest()
        {
            CyclicQueue Q = new CyclicQueue(5);
            Q.Enqueue(1);
            Assert.AreEqual(1, Q.Front);
            Q.Enqueue(2);
            Assert.AreEqual(1, Q.Front);
            Assert.AreEqual(2, Q.Rear);
            Q.Enqueue(3);
            Assert.AreEqual(1, Q.Front);
            Assert.AreEqual(3, Q.Rear);

            Assert.AreEqual(1, Q.Dequeue());
            Assert.AreEqual(2, Q.Front);
            Assert.AreEqual(3, Q.Rear);

            Assert.AreEqual(2, Q.Dequeue());
            Assert.AreEqual(3, Q.Front);
            Assert.AreEqual(3, Q.Rear);

            Assert.AreEqual(3, Q.Dequeue());
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void QueueOverflowTest()
        {
            CyclicQueue Q = new CyclicQueue(5);
            Q.Enqueue(1);
            Q.Enqueue(2);
            Q.Enqueue(3);
            Q.Enqueue(4);
            Q.Enqueue(5);
            Assert.AreEqual(1, Q.Dequeue());
            Q.Enqueue(6);
            Assert.AreEqual(2, Q.Front);
            Assert.AreEqual(6, Q.Rear);
        }
    }

    public class CyclicQueue
    {
        public int[] _buffer;
        private int _start;
        private int _end;
        private int _size;
        private int _maxSize;
        public CyclicQueue(int maxSize)
        {
            _maxSize = maxSize;
            _buffer = new int[_maxSize];
            _start = 0;
            _end = 0;
        }
        public void Enqueue(int newValue)
        {
            if (_size == _maxSize)
            {
                throw new OutOfMemoryException("Queue at full capacity");
            }
            if (_size > 0)
            {
                _end = (_end + 1) % _maxSize;
            }
            _buffer[_end] = newValue;
            _size++;
        }

        public int Dequeue()
        {
            if (_size == 0)
            {
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Queue is empty");
            }

            int result = _buffer[_start];
            _size--;

            _start = (_start + 1) % _maxSize;
            return result;
        }
        public int Front
        {
            get { return _buffer[_start]; }
        }

        public int Rear
        {
            get { return _buffer[_end]; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Yay exceptions!

Though it isn't reservered for execution-ending errors, I would avoid throwing an `OutOfMemoryException`, because usually it signals something very inconvient indeed. `IndexOutOfRangeException` also seems inappropriate: I would probably use [`InvalidOperationException`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.invalidoperationexception?view=netframework-4.8) in both `Enqueue` and `Dequeue`.

The constructor could do with a check to ensure `maxSize` is positive, so that it doesn't throw with a cryptic error.

`Front` and `End` don't throw on an empty buffer, and probably should.

### API and Encapsulation

There is no reason this class couldn't be generic: I would make it so. Indeed, because it stores `int`s at the moment, it would not be clear to a consumer looking at the members that `Front` and `Rear` return elements rather than indexes.

I'd expect a `Count => _size` property, so that the Queue can be used for the sort of things Queues tend to be used (e.g. in your previous questions).

Do you have a particular use-case in mind for exposing `_buffer`? What good can come of this? There is no information made available as to the content of the buffer, so it can't be used for anything because nothing except the `CyclicQueue` knows how to use it. I would strongly suggest making this private (also, if it is public, it should ideally following the `ProperCamelCase` naming conventions like your other public members).

Since this is a non-resizing queue, the `MaxSize` probably ought to be public information. I'd also consider making it `MaxSize => _buffer.Length` to reduce redundancy. You could also make `_buffer` readonly to signal it's not meant to be changed to the maintainers.

### Correctness

I'm not sure the `_size > 0` check in `Enqueue` works. Consider a sequence of `Enqueue`, (`Dequeue`, `Enqueue`)`*n` on a newly created `CyclicQueue`: this will leave `_end = 0` while `_start` is incremented. I think this can be resolved by setting `_end = _maxSize - 1` in the constructor and removing the check.

### Misc/Boring Stuff

- You could do with a little more white-space between things... at the very least, be consistent with your between-member spacing.
- You could do with tests which test the exceptions (i.e. checking it throws if you try to enqueue/dequeue too many things.
- As always, inline-documentation would be appreciated. This should describe the non-resizing nature of the queue, when it throws exceptions, and resolve the confusion concerning whether `Front` is an index or element.

Comment: I always like and appreciate your reviews! Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

Wouldn't it be possible to calculate the `_end` as

```
      private int End => (_start + _size) % _maxSize;
```

so you only have to update `_start` and `_size` and then omit `_end`?

`Enqueue` will then look as:

```
  public void Enqueue(T newValue)
  {

    if (_size == _maxSize)
    {
      throw new InvalidOperationException("Queue at full capacity");
    }

    _buffer[End] = newValue;
    _size++;
  }
```